# How to take data from MDF file and create a table with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am trying to take data from a file and create a table with it. The program already works and it takes in user inputted information and inserts it into an MDF file. I can take the information from the file and create a string with it and show the string. But I want to format it so it shows up in a table instead of it showing each record as a string in a list. This is the code I have to get the information from the database, and what I use to show it as a list of strings.

This is what I use to get the information from the database and create a string with it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

// The Model that has all the getter and setter methods for the rentals

namespace SimpleForm.Models
{
public partial class Rentals
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set;  }
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public string MemberIDNumb { get; set; }
    public string RentalLength { get; set; }
    public string IsMember { get; set; }
    public string MovieFormat { get; set; }

    //String that is returned in the view page.
    //Shows all the information from each rental
    public string InfoString
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + "," + FirstName + "," + IsMember + "," + MemberIDNumb + "," + MovieTitle + "," + MovieFormat + "," + RentalLength;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code to show the information when the page is loaded.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="view-
rentals.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleForm.viewrentals" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="RentalsInfo">
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Member?</td>
                <td>Member ID</td>
                <td>Movie Title</td>
                <td>Movie Format</td>
                <td>Rental Length</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResults"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use datagrid or grid view control to display data in tabular format https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-in-GridView-in-ASPNet-from-SQL-Server.aspx